# A commutative diagram for $F(\alpha) \cong F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I've been trying to understand the following proposition:

*Let $E$ be a field extension of $F$ and $\alpha \in E$ be algebraic over $F$. Then, $F(\alpha) \cong F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ where $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$*

The book's proof states:

*Let $\phi_\alpha: F[x] \rightarrow E $ be the evaluation homomorphism. The kernel of this map is $\langle p(x) \rangle$, where $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. By the first isomorphism theorem for rings, the image of $\phi_\alpha$ in E is isomorphic to $F(\alpha)$ since it contains both $F$ and $\alpha$.*

Here is what I understand:

- The kernel of $\phi_\alpha$ is $\langle p(x) \rangle$ since it consists of all multiples of $p(x)$
- We can use the first isomorphism theorem to state that there is an isomorphism $\phi_\alpha(F[x]) \cong F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ since $\langle p(x) \rangle$ is the kernel of $\phi_\alpha$.

I've made a small diagram to help myself:

[image: commutative diagram]

where $\Phi_{F[x]}$ is the canonical homomorphism from $F[x]$ to $F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$.

Now, here are the two things I don't get:

1. What can we use to map from $F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ to $\phi_\alpha(F[x])$?
2. How is it using the first isomorphism theorem to show that $F(\alpha) \cong \phi_\alpha(F[x])$?

Ideally, I would like to get to a commutative diagram showing $F(\alpha) \cong F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$.

Thanks a lot for the help!

*edits: removed $E = \phi_\alpha(F[x])$, updated question 2.*

Comment: What book are you reading? It looks to me like the ingredient you are missing is the universal property of the quotient (which your book may or may not discuss when it covers the first isomorphism theorem for rings). But you also seem to be a bit confused: $E$ is not necessarily the image of $\phi_{\alpha}$, nor is it necessarily isomorphic (or equal to) $F(\alpha)$. It might help to review the definition of $F(\alpha)$, and to review the statement and proof of the first isomorphism theorem for rings.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. From my understanding, $F(\alpha)$ is a field extension of $F$ which contains both $F$ and $\alpha$.  What I don't get is how using the first isomorphism theorem helps us to show $F(\alpha) \cong \phi_\alpha(F[x])$. I thought that this could be showed simply from the definition of $\phi_\alpha$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map you are missing is nothing but the induced map from the Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphisms. Given a coset $g(x)+\langle p(x)\rangle \in F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, the map sends it to $g(\alpha)$. It's the only map that could possibly fit, which you can see by starting with $g(x)$ in the upper left hand corner.

The fact that $p(\alpha)=0$ ensures the map is well defined. The fact that $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ ensures it is an isomorphism onto its image.

Note that no one is claiming that $E$ equals the image. So your second point is a *mis*understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now! I also get that $E$ is not necessarily equal to $\phi_\alpha(F[x])$. 
Now, why is the book stating: *By the first isomorphism theorem for rings, the image of $\phi_\alpha$ in $E$ is isomorphic to $F(\alpha)$ [...]*. I don't see where the first isomorphism theorem is relevant here. I understand that we use it to show $\phi_\alpha(F[x]) \cong F[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle$, not $\phi_\alpha(F[x]) \cong F(\alpha)$.

Comment: @pedropedro Because $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\cong F(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit formula of the isomorphism $\tau: F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\overset{\cong}{\to} F(\alpha)$ is
\begin{equation}
g(x)+ \langle p(x)\rangle\mapsto g(\alpha).
\end{equation}

You can directly check that it is an isomorphism. Be careful that we need to show the well-definedness. In fact, if $g_1(x)+ \langle p(x)\rangle=g_2(x)+ \langle p(x)\rangle$, then $p\mid g_1-g_2$. Therefore $g_1(\alpha)-g_2(\alpha)=0$, i.e. $g_1(\alpha)=g_2(\alpha)$, and this proves the well-definedness. That $\tau$ is bijective and is a ring homomorphism is easy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna convert my comment as an answer beacuse it addresses directly your second question.

> How is it using the first isomorphism theorem to show that $F(\alpha)\cong\phi_\alpha(F[x])$?

Note that by definitition $\phi_\alpha(F[x]) = F[\alpha]$ and $F(\alpha)$ is the smallest field which contains both $F$ and $\alpha$ (so clearly it is always true that $F[\alpha]\subseteq  F(\alpha)$). Since $p(x)$ is irreducible and $F[x]$ is a PID, $F[\alpha] \cong F[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle$ is a field (containing both $F$ and $\alpha$), it follows that $F[\alpha]=F(\alpha)$.